# Can I call VariantChangeType on an input BSTR VARIANT?

Tags: c++, com, variant, bstr

I have a COM object written in C++ with a method using the following signature. Assume that the variant contains a BSTR (just VT_BSTR, not VT_BYREF | VT_BSTR).

```
HRESULT myfunc(/*[in]*/ VARIANT param)
```

I want to change the type to something else. If the first parameter of [VariantChangeType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221258(v=vs.85).aspx) is the same as the second, the "variant will be converted in place."

So, can I convert in place?

```
HRESULT myfunc(/*[in]*/ VARIANT param)
{
    VariantChangeType(&param, param, 0, VT_I4);
}
```

Or should I copy to a second variant?

```
HRESULT myfunc(/*[in]*/ VARIANT param)
{
    VARIANT temp;
    VariantInit(&temp);
    VariantChangeType(&temp, param, 0, VT_I4);
}
```

My understanding is that the latter is required, since the former would free the BSTR, which is owned by the client and should be freed by the client.

Comment: No, VariantChangeType() stores the result into another variant.  The one you pass as the 1st argument.  So it has no reason at all to release the BSTR.  Unless you did something unwise with the result variable so it is not empty, like using VariantCopy :)

Comment: @HansPassant The first parameter to VariantChangeType() can be the same as the second, meaning the variant will be converted in place. So, perhaps better stated, should I convert in place or convert to a second variant? I've updated the question to clarify.

Comment: FWIW, I created a Gist to demonstrate the problem: https://gist.github.com/Neuroboy23/efb3d45783faf03bd87ee2a69519ce84

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`VariantChangeType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221258(v=vs.85).aspx) with a second variant is required, although it may not be obvious.

Even though the variant is passed by value, any pointers contained in the variant point to the same memory addresses. Since a BSTR is a pointer, that means the original address of the BSTR is passed into the function, just as if the parameter were BSTR instead of VARIANT.

Using `VariantChangeType` (in-place) or [`VariantClear`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221165(v=vs.85).aspx) will trigger [`SysFreeString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221481(v=vs.85).aspx), meaning that the original variant (owned by the caller) still contains the address of the BSTR but that address no longer holds the BSTR.

From the ["Variant Manipulation Functions"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation...

> When releasing or changing the type of a variant with the VT_BSTR type, SysFreeString is called on the contained string.

The reason this isn't obvious is that this code seems to work, even though everything I described above says it shouldn't.

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif // !WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <OleAuto.h>

HRESULT myfuncbad(/*[in]*/ VARIANT param)
{
    // In-place conversion
    VariantChangeType(&param, &param, 0, VT_I4);
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT myfuncgood(/*[in]*/ VARIANT param)
{
    VARIANT temp;
    VariantInit(&temp);
    // Copy and convert into a new VARIANT
    VariantChangeType(&temp, &param, 0, VT_I4);
    VariantClear(&temp);
    return S_OK;
}

int main()
{
    VARIANT input;
    VariantInit(&input);
    V_BSTR(&input) = SysAllocString(L"1");
    V_VT(&input) = VT_BSTR;

    myfuncgood(input);
    wprintf(L"Memory location of BSTR = 0x%x\n", (unsigned)(V_BSTR(&input)));
    wprintf(L"Contents of BSTR = %s\n", V_BSTR(&input));

    myfuncbad(input);
    wprintf(L"Memory location of BSTR = 0x%x\n", (unsigned)(V_BSTR(&input)));
    wprintf(L"Contents of BSTR = %s\n", V_BSTR(&input));
}
```

This code runs and outputs something like the following

```
Memory location of BSTR = 0x2d1af0c
Contents of BSTR = 1
Memory location of BSTR = 0x2d1af0c
Contents of BSTR = 1
```

But why? Turns out that [BSTR allocations are cached](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091127-00/?p=15883). So, even when `VariantChangeType` (in-place) or `VariantClear` is called, the BSTR allocation may stick around for a while. It will be immediately obvious on the variant passed into those functions, but any "by-value" copy of the variant may still see the BSTR for some time.

Regardless, the BSTR has, technically, been freed by `myfuncbad` and should no longer be referenced by the caller. Also, calling `VariantClear` on the original variant may cause errors.

Additional reading

- [Why is there a BSTR cache anyway?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150107-00/?p=43203)
- [Caches are nice, but they confuse memory leak detection tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091127-00/?p=15883/)
- [Eric's Complete Guide To BSTR Semantics](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/12/erics-complete-guide-to-bstr-semantics/)
- [Extending Visual Basic - The Ultimate Data Type](http://web.archive.org/web/20031121161357/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/archive/en-us/dnarextvb/html/msdn_article4.asp)

Comment: What's important here is the /*[in]*/ annotation. It means the idl has it and so the passed-in buffer is not yours. It's read-only for the callee. So you can't change that buffer. That's all about it.

Answer (score 0):

The inplace conversion is save. You don't need a temporal variant.

I use it in all of my ATL COM code with something like this:

```
CComVariant v;
GetSomeData(v);  // Assume v returns a VT_BSTR variant.
HRESULT hr = v.ChangeType(VT_I4);
if (FAILED(hr))
    ...
```

This code translates into an inplace conversion in the discussed way.
Internally the result is calculated with `VarI4FromBSTR` before the old `VARIANT` `BSTR` usage count value is decremented.

I validated this in some debug sessions because I wasn't sure about this too.

**EDIT** And finally I found the statement in the [MSDN that confirms this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms221673(v=vs.85).aspx).

> For VT_BSTR, there is only one owner for the string. All strings in
>   variants must be allocated with the SysAllocString function. When
>   releasing or changing the type of a variant with the VT_BSTR type,
>   SysFreeString is called on the contained string.

That the code works in the answer of @jveazey It has nothing to do with BSTR caching. There is a real inplace conversion!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a dangerous answer. In the example you provide, it's safe because you're receiving the `VARIANT` from a method call -- once that method call is complete, the owner of the `VARIANT` and its contained `BSTR` is the caller, and it's fine if the caller wants to convert it. But OP's question is about a situation in which the `VARIANT` and its contained `BSTR` are being passed into a method. In this case, it's not safe to change the type because you (the callee) will be deallocating something that is owned by the caller (who will later try to deallocate it again).

Comment: MSDN explicitly states "When releasing or changing the type of a variant with the VT_BSTR type, SysFreeString is called on the contained string." The callee (myfuncbad) in the example is bad because it is freeing something owned by the caller.

Comment: Added link to the MSDN that confirms my answer!

Comment: The callee is NOT the owner in OP. In the method signature, the argument is an `[in] VARIANT`. In the C++, this is a `VARIANT`, not a `VARIANT*`. When the method is called, the `VARIANT` struct will be byte copied (the `BSTR` pointer is copied, not the `BSTR` itself). This means that when the callee uses `VariantChangeType`, the referenced `BSTR` is freed. However, the caller is the owner, and it won't know that the callee freed the `BSTR` (because the caller's struct is not modified by the callee's `VariantChangeType` call). The caller will then deallocate it's `VARIANT` and it will crash.

Comment: I don't understand about what function you are talking. VariantChangeType takes VARIANT*... I am not using the myfuncbad and myfuncgood. This is indeed bad design. I was just answering the question about VariantChangeType. And I only said that the inplace version of VariantChangeType is OK. All you what you are wrting should be a comment to the asker. Or am I wrong? What is wrong with my anser. I have no [in] parameter in my sample...

Comment: I'm talking about the code provided in the original question. The original question wasn't asking if it's generally safe to use `VariantChangeType` with identical first two parameters (it isn't -- it's only safe in some scenarios). The question asks about the safety in a specific scenario -- that of calling it within a callee which takes an `[in] VARIANT`. You are providing an answer for a different scenario.

I have written the necessary code to demonstrate the problem.
https://gist.github.com/Neuroboy23/efb3d45783faf03bd87ee2a69519ce84

Comment: @MichaelGunter  - you should make an answer of your own :-)

Answer (score -1):

It would be safer to make a copy, but as I read "The Rules of the Component Object Model" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810016.aspx):

•The following rules apply to parameters to interface member functions, including the return value, that are not passed "by-value":
◦For in parameters, the caller should allocate and free the memory.

The case you are talking about is a pass-by-value (regardless of the VARIANT happening to contain a BSTR for this call). So I believe the callee owns the parameter in this case and it is up to the caller to make the copy if it wants to ensure continued viability of its value.

Comment: A BSTR is a pointer allocated by SysAllocString. So, it is a reference, even if it isn't a VT_BYREF. So, technically, it's not passed "by-value".

Comment: I'm with @jveazey on this one. The caller is always going to try to deallocate its `VARIANT`, and if any contained memory has already been deallocated, that's gonna be a crash.